# What is the avarage build time for a gatsby-theme ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a gatsby-theme ReactJS application and the build time for this application is more than 6 minutes. Is this normal? If not what are the steps to troubleshoot and optimize the build time for the gatsby-theme

Answer (score 1):

1. It's unclear from your description if you're referring to a site built using Gatsby, or building a Gatsby [Theme](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/themes/)... I'll assume the former, though it makes little difference.
2. A 6-minute build time isn't unusual (depending on your site/hardware), and nothing to be concerned about. Most of your development can be done with hot-reloading using `gatsby develop`. The build process takes so much longer because of all the optimizations made upfront — which is what makes Gatsby sites so fast in production
3. You won't find any [silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet) to magically improve performance; it all depends on the individual requirements of your project (thousands of pages? tons of high-resolution images? lots of external API requests? etc.). The Gatsby [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/performance/) have a whole section on performance, although that's more focused on user experience; if images are your bottleneck, see the section on [preoptimizing your images](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/preoptimizing-images/), for example.

If 6 minutes seems like a long time to wait for a CI job to run, just think of all the development time you're saving with tools like `gatsby-image` and the rest of the Gatsby ecosystem!

Hope this helps.

---

EDIT: just recalled that if you really want to dive in and examine build performance, Gatsby is instrumented with OpenTracing — so you can always hook into Jaeger, Zipkin, or other OpenTracing-compatible tool. (source: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/performance-tracing/)